# Get data from two tables in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, foreign-keys

I have two tables `emp` and `requisition`

`emp.rb`

```
 class Emp < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :requisitions 


 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:confirmable,:lockable


     attr_accessor :email

     attr_accessible :password,:password_confirmation,:remember_me, :email , :username
     string_regex = /\A[a-z]+\z/i
     validates :username,
     :format => { :with => string_regex ,:message=> "must be string"},
      :uniqueness => {
:case_sensitive => false
}
end
```

`Requisition`

```
class Requisition < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :emp

attr_accessible :name , :unit , :quantity ,:from ,:particular ,:total , :cost

validates :name , :unit , :quantity ,:from ,:particular ,:total , :cost , presence: true

 validates :particular, :presence => true,
          :length => { :within => 6..60 }

  validates :quantity, numericality: { only_integer: true },
          :length => {:maximum => 4}

  validates :quantity, numericality: { only_integer: true },
          :length => {:maximum => 4}

end
```

If i want to count the number of requisition of emp what edit should i have to do?

In my log

```
irb(main):002:0> @emp.requisitions.count
(1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "requisitions" WHERE "requisitions"."emp_id" =$1  [[nil, 2]]
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column requisitions.emp_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "requisitions"  WHERE "requisitions"."e...: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "requisitions"  WHERE "requisitions"."emp_id" = $1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column requisitions.emp_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "requisitions"  WHERE "requisitions"."e...
                                               ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "requisitions"  WHERE "requisitions"."emp_id" = $1from  F:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:811:in `prepare
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, `belongs_to` association name should be singular, so you should have

```
belongs_to :emp
```

in your `Requisition` model.

You should also generate migration adding `emp_id` column to `requisitions` table:

```
bundle exec rails g migration add_emp_id_to_requisitions emp:references
```

and run it:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Now, given you have `emp` variable that holds `Emp` instance, you can count this `emp`'s `requisition` by:

```
emp.requisitions.count
```

Comment: @SNEHPANDYA You forgot about migration. I expanded my answer.